# Mapping <C, \> in vim

Tags: vim, keymap

I'm trying to add a key mapping from Ctrl-j to Ctrl-\ s. This is to make my life a bit easier when using cscope. I've tried the following mapping:

```
map <C-J> <C,\\>s
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've also tried various combinations, such as `map Ctrl-j Ctrl-<Bslash> s` and nothing seems to work. I've consulted `:help key-notation` and `:help map_backslash` but as far as I can tell I'm following the directions in there to a T. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mapping:

```
map <C-J> <C-\>s
```

Comment: Good god. I swear I tried that. Welp, thanks for the help sir.